# Vagrant installation on Windows 8.0.1

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have a problem with virtualbox.
I see this error when start VirtualBox. Anybody know what error is it?

Unable to load R3 module C:\Program files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD): GetLastError=1790 (VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR).

Error log: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Компонент: 
Console
Интерфейс: 
IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}

Comment: May you try to switch off antivirus and try again?

Comment: I don't have antivirus

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this topic](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13504?cversion=1&cnum_hist=1), 4.3.12 is the last version that works reliably. This issue is caused by `uxtheme.dll`. You can try it.